# How to properly write a string to a named pipe and the difference between echo and printf

Tags: linux, echo, fifo, printf

**Problem:**

I need to send a command to a named pipe and need to ensure only the command is sent and not any errant or "fat-fingered" characters.

**Example:**

I have been using the following:

```
echo "command" > /path/to/namedPipe
```

This works fine, but I noticed something odd, that it is possible to send errant keystrokes to the pipe.  For example:

```
echo "command" > /path/to/namedPipe straycharacters
```

then both `<command>` and `<straycharacters>` are written to namedPipe.  I would not have guessed this would happen, but in some cases it can really mess up my program.  I also noticed echo does not seem to require quotes.  My command does not require quotes, just the actual `<command>`.  What would be the best practice to write only `<command>` to the pipe?

**Possible Solution:**

`printf "command" > /path/to/namedPipe straycharacters`

In my terminal this only prints out `<command>` and not `<straycharacters>`, and so far it appears to be compatible with my program.  However it is a little different than echo because it seems to not include a new line.

Comment: That's because the first argument to `printf` is a format string. If it contained `%s`, `%d`, etc., the remaining arguments will be printed accordingly. How do you guarantee you won't fat finger the first argument?

Comment: Use single quotes rather than double quotes, it means that dollar is not special so one less thing to fat finger. However reading the fine manual is always a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command

```
echo "command" > /path/to/namedPipe straycharacters
```

is equivalent to

```
echo "command" straycharacters >/path/to/namedPipe
```

(compare [this](https://superuser.com/q/1335333/432690)) and `echo` prints all its operands, so in this case `straycharacters` as well. Similarly your "working" solution is equivalent to

```
printf "command" straycharacters >/path/to/namedPipe
```

and it "works" only because

- `command` apparently doesn't include fragments that would be interpreted by the shell in a non-literal fashion (like `${PATH}`);
- `command` apparently doesn't include fragments that would be interpreted by `printf` in a non-literal fashion; note `command` is interpreted as format (see `man 1 printf` for details); if there was `%s` there, `straycharacters` would be substituted.

The right way to pass `command` (and a newline) is

```
printf '%s\n' 'command' >/path/to/namedPipe    # straycharacters
```

where

- `\n` is responsible for printing a newline character;
- `straycharacters` appear in the comment;
- all strings that should should be passed to `printf` literally are single-quoted (although you may want to double-quote `command`, e.g. if it relies on parameter substitution by design).

Having "errant or fat-fingered characters" in your code is wrong. Instead of trying to find syntax that ignores them, just remove this garbage and pay attention. This will make your code clean and nice.

Still, even without `straycharacters`, `echo` is not a right tool. See [*Why is printf better than echo?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, now I understand `printf`.  In my case I can just use '`%s'` and do not need the `\n` because I want to make sure junk typed after `namedPipe` is not passed in.  I am actually running the command as an exec node in nodeRed and (it's probably something dumb I am doing) but the symptom is that extra junk is appended after `namedPipe` and that kills my program.  So I do not want a comment or `strayCharacters` and I'm trying to make sure `command` and ONLY `command` is what the program receives.

Comment: After some further testing I see what you mean about the `#`.   It will truly block any extra characters.  And with the `\n` it is working great so far.  So in nodeRed I issue the command at the exec node like this:  `printf '%s\n' 'command' >~/namedPipe #` and if for whatever reason extra junk is appended it will simply be seen as a comment.  I wish I could log what the actual command sent to the pipe is but I have not figured that out yet.